# 301 redirect in htaccess doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, migration

I've made an htaccess file, but several testers tell me it's not right.
Domain B is going offline and I want to redirect all the pages to new pages on domain A.

This is the code:

```
redirect 301 / https://domain-A.com/
redirect 301 /page-1/domain-B/ https://domain-A.com/page-1/
redirect 301 /page-2/domain-B/ https://domain-A.com/page-2/
```

Comment: And what is the specific issue? "it's not right" does not really help. What exactly do the testers tell you what the issue is?

Comment: Um... you state that "Domain B is going offline" - yet you explicitly try to redirect requests to exactly that domain in your setup ...

Comment: You're right, my bad. I've edited it.

For example this tester: https://technicalseo.com/tools/htaccess/

When I fill in the first line: ```redirect 301 / https://domain-A.com/``` the rest of the redirects will return it's ***not reached*** and ***not met***.

When I leave out the first redirect, the other redirect will return ***reached***, but will ***not return met***.

Comment: OK, so there you have your answer yourself: that test tool tells you what's wrong. You always need to implement specific rules _earlier_ (further up) in your configuration, so that they can match first. More general rules belong _later_ (further down) to act as a catch-all.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> redirect 301 / https://domain-A.com/
> redirect 301 /page-1/domain-B/ https://domain-A.com/page-1/
> redirect 301 /page-2/domain-B/ https://domain-A.com/page-2/
> ```

Your rules are in the wrong order. The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching. The first rule redirects *everything* (and preserves the URL-path). The second and third rules are never processed. (What exactly is the "tester" reporting? Is this a thrid party tool or a real "tester" person?)

If you request `/page-1/domain-B/` you will see that you are not redirected as intended. (You are redirected to `https://domain-A.com/page-1/domain-B/`, not `https://domain-A.com/page-1/` as would seem to be the intention.)

You need to reverse the order of these rules. The most specific needs to be first.

For example:

```
Redirect 301 /page-1/domain-B/ https://domain-A.com/page-1/
Redirect 301 /page-2/domain-B/ https://domain-A.com/page-2/
Redirect 301 / https://domain-A.com/
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the erroneous 301s will have been cached by the browser. Test first with 302 redirects to avoid caching issues.

> `/page-1/domain-B/`

And `/domain-B/` is actually in the URL-path?

Comment: Allright, that clears a lot. Thanks!

The tester is a third party.

However, I still get a ***not met*** when I do it like your example.

Domain B is not ***in*** the URL-path. It's a page on domain B. I could've also leave out /domain-B/. I added it to make clear page-1 is on domain B. So another example: 

```redirect 301 /page-1-domain-B/ https://domain-A.com/page-1/```

Comment: Presumably in that case you are requesting the URL `/page-1-domain-B/`? If that rule is "not met" then you likely have another rule that is conflicting. Please update your question to include your complete `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Well my htaccess file is about hundreds of redirects, so I just tested 3 redirects to see if it works. And only the homepage redirect works. Even if I only test one page redirect, like:

```redirect 301 /page-1/domain-B/ https://domain-A.com/page-1/```

So also with no other rules, it's not working

Comment: "hundreds of pages long" - quite likely you have a conflict then! Have you tested these 3 redirects in isolation, having archived your existing `.htaccess` file? Presumably this `.htaccess` file is only used to redirect from domainB to domainA (on a different server)?

Comment: If you only have a single `Redirect` rule and it's not working then either **1.** You are seeing a cached response. **2.** the request is not reaching your server. **3.** `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled. **4.** You are requesting a different URL?!

Comment: _Aside:_ Testing tools are _flawed_. You can only reasonably test this on a real server.

Comment: Allright. Then I think I should first test it on the server instead of a third party tool. I'll try that first. Thanks a lot for your help Mr. White!